# Can every adjective be after a noun?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

I’ve heard that [noun] [adjective] equals [noun] [that is] [adjective]. But, then can every adjective be after a noun?

> She is a girl cute.
>   This is a book interesting.
>   The dog black is mine.
>   France is a country famous for its beautiful sights.

Comment: All of those sentences are technically grammatical. Aside from the last one however, they are not very idiomatic. Putting an adjective after a noun is commonly only done in poetry, since it's not the normal order of phrasing that's used in regular conversation or writing. It's not *wrong*, but it's also not entirely natural.

Comment: Thank you. Is [noun] [adjective] used neither in U.K. nor U.S.A?

Comment: You misunderstand. It *is* used, just in a very narrow context—such as with poetry or other pieces of writing where the same stylistic effect is desired.

Comment: I see. Then do you use that in writing casual or formal texts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't typically do that with a single word adjective, but you would with an adjective phrase.

> I met a girl cute as can be.
>
> This is a book interesting to people who love computers, but no one else.
>
> That dog with eyes black as coal is mine.
>
> France is a country famous for its beautiful sights.
>
> A person smarter than me needs to figure this out.
>
> Students upset about the rising cost of tuition staged a rally.

I got some examples from https://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-phrase-examples.html even though some of their examples might be participle phrases.

Comment: Thank you! Do you use that in writing casual or formal texts or daily conversations?

Comment: In writing, like in a news article, definitely. In everyday speech, possibly not, at least I can't think of any examples.  You'd be more apt to say something like "Somebody smarter than me needs to figure this out."

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're a bit confused. Instead of `[noun] [adjective]`, it should be `[adjective] [noun]`. So, your original idea becomes,

> [adjective] [noun] equals [noun] [that is] [adjective].

And it's true for every sentence that you've mentioned.

> **She is a cute girl.**
>
> She's a girl that is cute.
>
> **This is an interesting book.**
>
> This is a book that is interesting.
>
> **The black dog is mine.**
>
> The dog that is black is mine.

Although grammatically correct, it might not sound so natural when you say it.

Comment: Thank you. I mistyped. But I heard that [noun] [adjective] equals [noun] [that is] [adjective]. The sentence starts with France has to be correct. I want to know when [noun] [adjective] is preferred.

Comment: The sentence is properly and completely 'France is a country that is famous...' so it comes under [noun][that is][adjective].

Comment: @simonatrcl: Or may be `France is a country famous for its **sights that are beautiful**`.